# Downcasting/Upcasting interface with generics to same interface but with different generics - C#

Tags: c#, oop, generics, interface

I want to downcast interface `IEntity<TM, TV, TP>` to `IEntity<IModel, IView, IPresenter>`, but it gives me Invalid Cast Exception. I added some constraints *(where)*, but it also didn't help.

*Note: Im not entirely sure what is this will do, upcast or downcast in my situation*

Better to show example in I try to use.

```cs
// Simple class, doesnt inherits anything.
// This class can't be generic
public class EntitiesContainer
{
    private List<IEntity<IModel, IView, IPresenter>> _entities = new ();

    // Adds IEntity<TM, TV, TC> to list of entities;
    public void Add<TM, TV, TC>(IEntity<TM, TV, TC> entity) 
        where TM : IModel 
        where TV : IView
        where TC : IPresenter
    {
        _entities.Add((IEntity<IModel, IView, IPresenter>)entity);  // invalid cast

        //or it says: argument type IEntity<TM, TV, TC> is not assignable to IEntity
        //_entities.Add(entity);  //syntax error
    }

    // some other methods below...
}
```

---

IEntity:

```cs
    public interface IEntity<TM, TV, TP> 
        where TM : IModel
        where TV : IView
        where TP : IPresenter
    {
        TM Model { get; }
        TV View { get; }
        TP Presenter { get; }
    }
```

This example I want to add IEntity to list. Class has a List of `IEntity<IModel, IView, IPresenter>`, but it is a problem to add `IEntity` with generic parameters. E.g. `IEntity<ImplModel, ImplView, ImplPresenter`, because it can't be downcasted/upcasted to <IEntity<IModel, IView, IPresenter>>

*ImplModel, ImplView, ImplPresenter- they all **Impl**ements its interfaces respectively (IModel, IView, IPresenter)*

I did some research. Looks like I need to use something called generics **covariance**. By documentation, I need to put *in* or *out* in class. But I have List of specific generics and *in* or *out* will not help.

---

Any help will be helpfull. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `out` specifier into your `IEntity` interface declaration and then remove cast completely

```
class TestModel:IModel{}
class TestView:IView{}
class TestPresenter:IPresenter{}

class TestEntity : IEntity<TestModel, TestView, TestPresenter>{}

// Simple class, doesnt inherits anything.
// This class can't be generic
public class EntitiesContainer
{
    private List<IEntity<IModel, IView, IPresenter>> _entities = new ();

    public void Test() => Add(new TestEntity());
    
    // Adds IEntity<TM, TV, TC> to list of entities;
    public void Add(IEntity<IModel, IView, IPresenter> entity) 
    {
        _entities.Add(entity);  // not cast at all
    }

    // some other methods below...
}

//------->>>Main changes here - *out* TModel, etc!!!
public interface IEntity<out TModel, out TView, out TPresenter>
    where TModel : IModel
    where TView: IView
    where TPresenter : IPresenter    
{
}

public interface IPresenter{}

public interface IView{}

public interface IModel{}
```

Comment: It works and invalid casts are gone. I added my IEntity class realization to question. Thanks for help!